# Code auto completion in an IDE

Tags: open-source, ide, autocomplete, intellisense

I use Microsoft’s Visual Studio, and find the IntelliSense code auto completion feature very useful.

Are there any alternative open source IDEs that offer a similarly useful feature?  How do they compare?

Comment: Many duplicates, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420341/where-can-i-download-a-free-c-ide-with-working-code-completion

Comment: @JonT: Like Neil Butterworth said, there are plenty of other answers for this on StackOverflow. It will usually help to search for a *specific* language, as many IDEs are tied to one language.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that an IDE that did not offer some completion capabilities would have low market acceptance.

In the Java world, Eclipse has code completion.

Answer (score 2):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) does quite a good job for Java development. Actually, it does a *very* good job.

PHP and Python plug-ins are available too. Probably other languages as well - you didn't mention any language in particular.

**Edit:** According to people more experienced than myself, Eclipse can be extended to provide "VERY VERY" good support for C and C++, too.

Comment: The latest version of CDT (C/C++ Development Tools) for Eclipse is VERY VERY good with code completion as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are many other IDEs that are open source, and most (if not all) of them feature some kind of auto completion.

Here's a link to Wikipedia's "[Comparison of IDEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments)", which might help.

You can also probably just search Stack Overflow for "Best IDE for x development" (x being the language you work with), and you'll find many options, all of them likely to have auto-completion.

One little "plug" for my favorite: [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) has much more than just auto-completion. If you're developing Java, it really opens your eyes to what kinds of things an IDE can do to help you out (compiling as you write and underlining errors, giving you a one-click way to make the IDE try and fix the problem for you, which it often does, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

[Scintilla](http://scintilla.org) is what you are looking for. It is a drop in replacement for an edit control. It has auto-complete capabilities as well as a host of other goodies. It is designed for C++ though, so it may not be an option, as you didn't specify a language.

Comment: Now that I see what you want, forget what I said. Eclipse is what you need, probably.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are refering to .NET IDEs as you mentioned Visual Studio.

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) is an .NET development software that indeed offer code completion. By the way, they use a full feature open-source text editor for that called ICSharpCode.TextEditor. I extended this text editor last year to support code-completion for database queries and it was very easy.